# Ignore warnings on F5 ( auto Debug Anyway )

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, debugging, .net-core

Running an ASP.NET Core code through <kbd>F5</kbd> hotkey (debug) if I have some Warning on the code it will stop the run until I press "Debug Anyway".

Is there an entry in the preferences to allow Debug either in presence of warnings ?

Comment: rly? Thats not the default, you have set something to make that happen. Maybe 'treat warnings as errors' in the project settings

Comment: yes, just try to run "dotnet new console" in a folder and then open that folder with vscode, declare some variable and don't use that in the code, then hit F5 I receive follow message: The preLaunchTask build terminated with exit code 1 with button "Debug Anyway" etc. May related to .vscode/launch.json ( I have to search in following [link1](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md) and [link2](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) ; it may related to Omnisharp or to the fact I using vscode insiders version )